# Dynamic redirect using ingress

Tags: service, routes, kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-ingress

I have 2 questions:

1) I have a kubernetes cluster with multiple services and I want to use ingress to dynamically redirect the traffic to the cluster.

I expect the configuration to look something like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /service1/*
        backend:
          serviceName: service1
          servicePort: 80
        path: /*
      - path: /service2/*
        backend:
          serviceName: service2
          servicePort: 80
        path:/*
```

So basically I want all the traffic to /service1/endpoint to be redirected to s1:80/endpoint dynamically.

2) Let's say I have 2 web services - service1 & service2.

I want the users to work with the following URL in their browser:

kube/serviceN/endpoint

Is there a way to do that without having my users redirected to service1/endpoint?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you deployed your ingress controller? Why two paths inside each path section?

Comment: and what about the second `path: /*` on every path definition? Plus the trailing `*` in `/service1/*` is not necessary! By default all paths starting with the defined pattern will be a match!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your ingress definition to be almost correct:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /service1
        backend:
          serviceName: service1
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /service2
        backend:
          serviceName: service2
          servicePort: 80
```

This should work if you have an ingress correctly deployed!

Comment: Seems to work just fine. 
I edited and added another question. 
Do you have an answer to my 2nd question? 
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly but switching the paths to  `path: /kube/service1` respectively `/kube/service2` should to the trick...?

Comment: I edited again to make it more clear.
The bottom line is that I want users to access the services via a cluster's endpoint. 

I don't want them to be redirected to the service URL, I want  them to keep using the kubernetes URL.

Comment: well, still - just switch from `- path: /service1` to `- path: /kube/service1`, or do you want both to work together?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood your question properly but if so, what you have provided as an example is pretty close to the mark. The below config should work as described.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /service1/
        backend:
          serviceName: service1
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /service2/
        backend:
          serviceName: service2
          servicePort: 80
```

Good luck :)